# Unable to access APIs after migrating WSO2 AM from 3.0.0 to 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I migrated WSO2 AM from 3.0.0 to 4.0.0 by following the wso2 docs. The migration was successful, however after migration I'm unable to call the APIs. I use Postman for the same.
I have a single node linux(VM-Amazon linux) setup, using Mysql(Amazon RDS) as my db.
I deployed a sample API that's provided by WSO2. When I call the API, I get a 404 in postman.
This is what I get in the carbon logs:

INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu, HEALTH CHECK URL = /pizzashack/1.0.0/menu

The attached snippet is the postman response.

```
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}
```

---

@Athiththan below is the TOML configuration for 4.0.0
Sorry for the poor formatting though.

```
[server]
hostname = "<hostname>"
#offset=0
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<mysql_here>:3306/apim_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"
username = "<user>"
password = "<password>"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<mysql_here>:3306/shared_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "<password>"
alias =  "<alias>"
key_password =  "<password>"

#[keystore.primary]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
#type =  "JKS"
#password =  "wso2carbon"
#alias =  "wso2carbon"
#key_password =  "wso2carbon"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}"
websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021"
websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"

[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Default"]

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

[apim.analytics]
enable = false
config_endpoint = "https://localhost:8080/auth/v1"
auth_token = ""

#[apim.key_manager]
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.idp]
#server_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}"
#authorize_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oauth2/authorize"
#oidc_logout_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/logout"
#oidc_check_session_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/oidc/checksession"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#convert_dialect = false
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.ExtendedDefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

#[apim.devportal]
#url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true
#enable_anonymous_mode=true
#enable_cross_tenant_subscriptions = true
#default_reserved_username = "apim_reserved_user"

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction","apikey","Internal-Key"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]
#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.17/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.17/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[database.local]
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"

[[event_listener]]
id = "token_revocation"
type = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.handler.AbstractIdentityHandler"
name = "org.wso2.is.notification.ApimOauthEventInterceptor"
order = 1
[event_listener.properties]
notification_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/internal/data/v1/notify"
username = "${admin.username}"
password = "${admin.password}"
'header.X-WSO2-KEY-MANAGER' = "default"

[encryption]
key = "<key_here>"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

Below is the TOML config for 3.0.0

```
[server]
hostname = "<hostname_here>"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[super_admin]
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "database"

[database.apim_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<mysql_here>:3306/apim_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

[database.shared_db]
type = "mysql"
url = "jdbc:mysql://<mysql_here>:3306/shared_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"
username = "<username>"
password = "<password>"

[keystore.tls]
file_name =  "wso2carbon.jks"
type =  "JKS"
password =  "<password>"
alias =  "<alias>"
key_password =  "<password>"

[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://localhost:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}"

#[apim.cache.gateway_token]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.resource]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "900s"

#[apim.cache.km_token]
#enable = false
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.recent_apis]
#enable = false

#[apim.cache.scopes]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.publisher_roles]
#enable = true

#[apim.cache.jwt_claim]
#enable = true
#expiry_time = "15m"

#[apim.cache.tags]
#expiry_time = "2m"

#[apim.analytics]
#enable = false
#store_api_url = "https://localhost:7444"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#event_publisher_type = "default"
#event_publisher_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher"
#publish_response_size = true

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7611","tcp://analytics2:7611"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7711","ssl://analytics2:7711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.analytics.url_group]]
#analytics_url =["tcp://analytics1:7612","tcp://analytics2:7612"]
#analytics_auth_url =["ssl://analytics1:7712","ssl://analytics2:7712"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.key_manager]
#service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#pool.init_idle_capacity = 50
#pool.max_idle = 100
#key_validation_handler_type = "default"
#key_validation_handler_type = "custom"
#key_validation_handler_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler"

#[apim.jwt]
#enable = true
#encoding = "base64" # base64,base64url
#generator_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.token.JWTGenerator"
#claim_dialect = "http://wso2.org/claims"
#header = "X-JWT-Assertion"
#signing_algorithm = "SHA256withRSA"
#enable_user_claims = true
#claims_extractor_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.token.DefaultClaimsRetriever"

#[apim.oauth_config]
#enable_outbound_auth_header = false
#auth_header = "Authorization"
#revoke_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/revoke"
#enable_token_encryption = false
#enable_token_hashing = false

#[apim.devportal]
#url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/devportal"
#enable_application_sharing = false
#if application_sharing_type, application_sharing_impl both defined priority goes to application_sharing_impl
#application_sharing_type = "default" #changed type, saml, default #todo: check the new config for rest api
#application_sharing_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.SAMLGroupIDExtractorImpl"
#display_multiple_versions = false
#display_deprecated_apis = false
#enable_comments = true
#enable_ratings = true
#enable_forum = true

[apim.cors]
allow_origins = "*"
allow_methods = ["GET","PUT","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS"]
allow_headers = ["authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Content-Type","SOAPAction"]
allow_credentials = false

#[apim.throttling]
#enable_data_publishing = true
#enable_policy_deploy = true
#enable_blacklist_condition = true
#enable_persistence = true
#throttle_decision_endpoints = ["tcp://localhost:5672","tcp://localhost:5672"]

#[apim.throttling.blacklist_condition]
#start_delay = "5m"
#period = "1h"

#[apim.throttling.jms]
#start_delay = "5m"

#[apim.throttling.event_sync]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 11224

#[apim.throttling.event_management]
#hostName = "0.0.0.0"
#port = 10005

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "loadbalance"

#[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
#traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://localhost:9611","tcp://localhost:9611"]
#traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://localhost:9711","ssl://localhost:9711"]
#type = "failover"

#[apim.workflow]
#enable = false
#service_url = "https://localhost:9445/bpmn"
#username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"
#callback_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/api/am/admin/v0.15/workflows/update-workflow-status"
#token_endpoint = "https://localhost:${https.nio.port}/token"
#client_registration_endpoint = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/client-registration/v0.15/register"
#client_registration_username = "$ref{super_admin.username}"
#client_registration_password = "$ref{super_admin.password}"

#data bridge config
#[transport.receiver]
#type = "binary"
#worker_threads = 10
#session_timeout = "30m"
#keystore.file_name = "$ref{keystore.tls.file_name}"
#keystore.password = "$ref{keystore.tls.password}"
#tcp_port = 9611
#ssl_port = 9711
#ssl_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#tcp_receiver_thread_pool_size = 100
#ssl_enabled_protocols = ["TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"]
#ciphers = ["SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5","SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"]

#[apim.notification]
#from_address = "APIM.com"
#username = "APIM"
#password = "APIM+123"
#hostname = "localhost"
#port = 3025
#enable_start_tls = false
#enable_authentication = true

#[apim.token.revocation]
#notifier_impl = "org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.events.TokenRevocationNotifierImpl"
#enable_realtime_notifier = true
#realtime_notifier.ttl = 5000
#enable_persistent_notifier = true
#persistent_notifier.hostname = "https://localhost:2379/v2/keys/jti/"
#persistent_notifier.ttl = 5000
#persistent_notifier.username = "root"
#persistent_notifier.password = "root"

[[event_handler]]
name="userPostSelfRegistration"
subscriptions=["POST_ADD_USER"]

[service_provider]
sp_name_regex = "^[\\sa-zA-Z0-9._-]*$"

[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<IP>:9611"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<IP>:9711"]
type = "loadbalance"

[passthru_http]
http.connection.timeout = 300000
http.socket.timeout = 300000

[synapse_properties]
synapse.global_timeout_interval = 300000
```

Can you please check for any mis-configuration.

Comment: Can you check whether the API is deployed properly? From 4.0.0 onward, the API should be deployed before publishing for it to be available on the gateway. This should be done by the migration client

Comment: Yes, it is deployed, all the 4 check points are in green in the publisher portal. And is also visible and subscribed in the developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

The following error can be observed when the Synapse Artifact of the mentioned API is not available in the API Manager Gateway.

```json
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}
```

You are able to see the APIs in both Publisher Portal and Devportal as they are fetched from Databases. However, for API invocation, the API Manager Gateway needs the API definition deployed as Synapse Artifact.

Try re-publishing the API from the Publisher portal to deploy the required Synapse Artifacts in the API Manager Gateway node | [Deploy a new revision](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/design/create-api/create-api-revisions/#depoly-a-new-revision)

1. Go to the Publisher portal
2. Open the respective API
3. Navigate to `Deploy` > `Deployments`
4. Click on `Deploy New Revision` and select the appropriate Gateway Environments and Deploy

This will create a new revision of the API and notifies the Gateway environments to fetch and deploy the Synapse Artifacts for API invocation.

#### Regarding TOML Configurations

Update the `gateway_labels` configuration in API Manager 4.0.0 as following

```ini
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway]
gateway_labels =["Production and Sandbox"]
```

The `gateway_labels` should match the values of the Gateway Environment names. Since you have configured a Gateway Environment with the name `"Production and Sandbox"`, the `gateway_labels` configuration needs to be updated as mentioned above.

Update the configurations, restart the API Manager server, and republish the APIs and try-out the scenario.

Comment: Hey, I did as you instructed, bu the error still persists. Is there any other step that needs to be followed after the revision deployent , like, restarting the server or something else?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors while deploying a new revision in your environment? Also, are you having a single node deployment or a distributed deployment? You can also restart the API Manager server and try invoking the API.

Comment: No errors while deploying the revision. Restarted the server as well, but the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have a distributed environment setup? or is it a single node API Manager running in your environment? Furthermore, have you verified and cross-checked the TOML configurations when migrating from 3.0.0 to 4.0.0? I am suspecting that this can be due to a misconfiguration, as republishing has not solved the problem. Were you able to create a new API in the environment and invoke it successfully?

Comment: This is a single node setup. I had placed the TOML configurations of both 3.0.0 and 4.0.0 side by side and then made the changes accordingly. Haven't tried creating a new API though. Can I comment the TOML configurations of both the 3.0.0 and 4.0.0 and maybe you can tell if there's some issue?

Comment: Yeah, submit the TOML configurations and also try publishing a new API from the migrated environment to verify whether new APIs are working as expected or not.

Comment: I've posted the TOML config below as an answer. Can you please check it?

Comment: You can edit the question and paste the TOML configurations, than putting them as an answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the changes related to TOML configurations.

Comment: The API isn't showing up in any of the portals be it publisher or devportal.

Comment: I published a mock hello world in the upgraded 4.0.0 and that showed up and is working fine but the previously published Sample API(Pizzashack) isn't available on the portals. Although I also tried to deploy a sample API again but got a message saying that the API has been already published. ERROR - GlobalThrowableMapper Error occurred while adding the API. The version already exists: 1.0.0 . So how do I get the previously published API back.

Comment: It seems your API Manager server's Solr directory has corrupted. Perform Step 7c (increase the number by one), 7d, and 7e from [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/upgrading-wso2-api-manager/upgrading-from-300-to-400/#step-3-restart-the-wso2-api-m-400-server) and restart the server.

Comment: *IT WORKED* Thank you so much . Will document these steps for future reference.